# Can I use Nginx Certbot to put ssl in an aws default ec2 domain?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, certbot

I tried to put the command to get the certificate but it gave me this error:
An unexpected error occurred:
The server will not issue certificates for the identifier :: Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for "ec2-34-237-242-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com": The ACME server refuses to issue a certificate for this domain name, because it is forbidden by policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's Encrypt blocks Amazon AWS domains because the domain names are transient and are subject to change.

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/policy-forbids-issuing-for-name-on-amazon-ec2-domain/12692/4

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative

1. Create a [subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/275982/what-type-of-dns-record-is-needed-to-make-a-subdomain) (api.example.com) for your domain (example.com)
2. Install a reverse proxy (like nginx) on your ec2 instance
3. Configure SSL for the reverse proxy.
4. Retain SSL for the app on your ec2 instance as usual.
5. Redirect https (and probably http also) traffic to your app in the reverse proxy (like nginx) conf.